# Add two parameters in function into "then" protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, protractor, end-to-end

It is quite clear. I have an array with some links and I want to build a loopto try all of them, but the problem is that link is always 3. It means that it read the last number in my array. Why? How can I fix it?

```
var categories = ['1','2','3'];
for( var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++ ) {
    var link = '/'+categories[i];
    browser.get(link);
    browser.sleep(2000);
    browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then( function(url) {
        expect(url).toMatch(link);
    });
}
```

and I have list of divs and I want to read randomly infos from them. So I made the following

```
chosenOffer         = Math.floor( (Math.random() * count ) + 1);
offer               = element.all( by.className('offer')).get( chosenOffer );
```

But it shows always error message chosenOffer object...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic closure problem that is described in detail in:

- [Using protractor with loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910331/using-protractor-with-loops)

In your case, just let `expect()` resolve the promise:

```
var categories = ['1','2','3'];

for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    var link = '/' + categories[i];
    browser.get(link);
    browser.sleep(2000);

    expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(link);
}
```

Comment: just another question chosenOffer         = Math.floor( (Math.random() * count ) + 1);
            // choose random offer todo fix it in protractor syntax
            offer               = element.all( by.className('offer')).get( offer ); why i get offer is object ...error

Comment: @dfr could you please make a separate question out of it (if it makes sense)? Thanks.

Comment: I re-edit my questions bc I need to wait 90 minutes to post new question