# JavaScript, variables scope, order of variable evaluation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm testing some angularjs app using protractor and have encountered such a problem:

```
var counter = 0;
redButton.click();
allImages.each(function(element) {
    element.isDisplayed().then(function(isDispl){
        if(isDispl === true){
            expect(element.getInnerHtml()).toContain('red');
            counter++;
            console.log("I'm here!")
        }
    });
});
console.log(counter);
```

The output is:

```
0
I'm here!
I'm here!
```

while I expected output:

```
I'm here!
I'm here!
2
```

Why so? Why variable counter does not equal 2 -- the number of times the condition isDispl === true is fullfiled?

Comment: Why did you expect that output?

Comment: You used a callback (the function you passed into "then"). That function is not called immediately but at some later point in the future.

Comment: This might also help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910331/using-protractor-with-loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one function can run at a time in JavaScript (that's simplifying a little, there are exceptions).

The main function runs all the way through before anything else happens. Since that function includes `console.log(counter);`, it logs the value of `counter` **at that time**.

Once the function has finished, the event loop can look for events that have fired.

The elements have been displayed so their promises trigger. Each time that happens (twice) you get a message and the value of `counter` changes.

Since this happens after the only time you output the value of `counter`, you never observe it reaching `2`.