# Looping over elements and testing them individually in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

Is there a way to implement loops so that the following code can be reduced?

```
    var navItems = element.all(by.repeater('item in mc.navItems'));
    expect(navItems.count()).toEqual(4);

    expect(navItems.get(0).getText()).toEqual('page1'.toUpperCase());
    navItems.get(0).click();
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toEqual('/page1');

    expect(navItems.get(1).getText()).toEqual('page2'.toUpperCase());
    navItems.get(1).click();
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toEqual('/page2');

    expect(navItems.get(2).getText()).toEqual('page3'.toUpperCase());
    navItems.get(2).click();
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toEqual('/page3');

    expect(navItems.get(3).getText()).toEqual('page4'.toUpperCase());
    navItems.get(3).click();
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toEqual('/page4');
```

I've tried multiple ways but they all fail because I'm not sure how to get them to wait until the promised value is returned.

Here's one way that fails:

```
var navItems = element.all(by.repeater('item in mc.navItems'));
for(var i = 0; i < navItems.count(); i++) {
    expect(navItems.get(i).getText()).toEqual(expectedValue[i].toUpperCase());
    navItems.get(i).click();
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toEqual('/' + expectedValue[i]);
}
```

where `expectedValue = ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'];`

The problem with this is that the for loop evaluates the condition even before the promised value is returned and so the contents of the loop are never executed.

I'm sure I can use a `then` and attach a callback function to `count()` but that would only make things messy because I'd have to make `navItems` a global variable so that it can be accessed by the callback function and I also need to make sure that `navItems` is populated before the callback function is executed.

I'm aware that the `expect()` method takes care of promises in a nice clean way, I would like to implement something like this.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using protractor with cucumber and what I do is something like this

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in mc.navItems')).then(function (elements) {
  navItems = elements
  var expectations = []
  for (var i = 0; i < navItems.count(); i++) {
    expect(navItems.get(i).getText()).toEqual(expectedValue[i].toUpperCase());
    navItems.get(i).click();
    expectations.push(expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toEqual('/' + expectedValue[i]));
  }
  Q.all(expectations).should.notify(callback)
})
```

so the test will wait for all expectations to execute before notifying callback

Comment: But the `for` loop still won't execute because `navItems.count()` is still not going to be equal to the length of `navItems` when the loop's execution commences. SIDE NOTE: I know I could just use `expectedValue.length` but I'd like to know how to use a `for` loop when the length is unknown.

Comment: I've edited my answer by creating the expectations when elements are returned

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the `each()` method was available at the time this question was asked, but these days I'm pretty sure `each()` is the best approach.

In the stated context, the answer would look something like:

```
var navItems = element.all(by.repeater('item in mc.navItems'));

navItems.each((element, index) => {
  expect(element.getText()).toEqual(('page'+index).toUpperCase());
  element.click();
  expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toEqual('/page'+index);
});
```

Much better than calling out each element individually!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that you have is not with the delay in return of promise but with closure. Take a look here-[Using protractor with loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910331/using-protractor-with-loops/27910350#27910350)
You can also use a recursion loop with `if` instead of using `for` as it is simpler-

```
function loop(i){
     if(i>=navItems.count())
              {
                return null;
              }
              else
              {
                expect(navItems.get(i).getText()).toEqual(expectedValue[i].toUpperCase());
        navItems.get(i).click();
        expectations.push(expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toEqual('/' + expectedValue[i]));
                })
            return loop(i+1)
          }
        }return loop(navItems.count());
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : first get the list of elements

```
let listOfElements = element.all(by.repeater('item in mc.navItems'));
```

Step 2: Iterate the element using below line

```
listOfElements.each(function (element, index) {
                    element.getText().then(function (text) {
                        console.log(index, text);
                    });
                });
```

Comment: This answer needs explanation