# How to use then() within loops using closures

Tags: javascript, loops, closures, promise, protractor

This question is very close to the question asked in [Using protractor with loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910331/using-protractor-with-loops) but still have not resolved by me in case of tiny difference.

```
// This script should print button names and its current numbers
var buttons = element.all(by.css('button'));
buttons.count().then(function(cnt){
  for(var i=0;i<cnt;i++) {
    var func = function(i2){ var k=i2; return function(){console.log("#"+k+", name: "+button_name);}}(i);
    buttons.get(i).getText().then(func);
  }
});
```

The compiler said "ReferenceError: button_name is not defined" that is right.
How can I pass the button name inside then() function?

Comment: What do you mean by button name? Button text or button name attribute?

Comment: Button text, but here it does not matter.

Comment: Shouldn't the parameter of your  `func`, i.e. the `i2`, be passed the result of the `getText()` promise?

Comment: The parameter i2 is not a parameter of func(). You see, the variable func is function that returned by function(i2), if I understood you.

Comment: Oh, right, I missed that function-returning-IEFE thing because of the lacking indentation. But then the solution is easy: `button_name` should be the parameter of `func` (which currently has none)

Comment: Is your final goal to get all the names of the buttons as an array?

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the function name as the argument to your `then` callback - but currently your `func` doesn't have a parameter. If you give it one, it'll work:

```
for (var i=0; i<cnt; i++) {
    var func = function(k) { 
        return function(button_name) {
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
            console.log("#"+k+", name: "+button_name);
        };
    }(i);
    buttons.get(i).getText().then(func);
}
```

or maybe without returning from the IEFE, ther more common pattern might be:

```
for (var i=0; i<cnt; i++) (function(k) {
    buttons.get(k).getText().then(function(button_name) {
//                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
        console.log("#"+k+", name: "+button_name);
    });
}(i));
```

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm not saying that this is the best way to use protactor, it's just how promises and closures work. I'd expect protractor to actually provide an iteration method - @finspin seems to have used it.</sub>

Comment: That's work fine, thank you!
I'm afraid to be boring but why ".then(func);" expression calls without argument that symbolize button text? Like ".then(func(b_text));"

Comment: It's the promise that calls your function and supplies the function - if you'd call it instead of passing it wouldn't work. Also, *you* don't have a `b_text` to pass…

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your intention correctly but if you want to print button `name` attribute and its index, this should do it:

```
$$('.button').forEach(function (button, index) {
    button.getAttribute('name').then(function (btnName) {
        console.log('#' + index + ', name: ' + btnName);
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually, my example is a little artificial. What I really want to understand how to use values from loops and promises with closures using. I know about others ways to solve this task. Corresponding to this case, how to print value 'i' from the loop and button name from the promise by one string.