# How to repeat a JavaScript function 5 times

Tags: javascript, protractor, repeat, e2e-testing

I'm testing an app with Protractor; I want to simulate a click on a button 5 times but I don't want to write the same code x5. how can I do it?

```
element(by.css('button.click')).click();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use loop

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
  element(by.css('button.click')).click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loops offer a quick and easy way to do something repeatedly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

If you're looking for Protractor with loops:

[Using protractor with loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910331/using-protractor-with-loops)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read documentation ... this is a basic

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    element(by.css('button.click')).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also do it with [`browser.actions()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions) chaining the click actions:

```
var link = element(by.css('button.click'));

actions = browser.actions();
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    actions = actions.click(link);
}
actions.perform();
```

As a side note, you can replace `element(by.css('button.click'))` with `$('button.click')` - protractor supports `$` and `$$` for CSS locators.