# Protractor how to assert multiple elements with same css class are all displayed

Tags: protractor

In protractor I would like to assert that all elements are displayed that have a particular css class. But syntax like this doesn't work.

```
expect(element.all(by.className('bill')).each(x => x.isDisplayed().toBeTruthy());
```

What's the protractor way of achieving this goal? Is this it?

```
let els = element.all(by.className('bill'));
els.then(x => {
  x.forEach(y => {
    expect(y.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
  })
});
```

This works, but seems overly complex.

Comment: It might work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910331/using-protractor-with-loops

Answer (score 2):

You could first convert the items to an array of booleans with `map` and then assert that the array doesn't contain `false`:

```
var elems = element.all(by.className('bill'));
expect(elems.map(e => e.isDisplayed())).not.toContain(false);
```

You coulds also use `reduce` to aggregate the state returned by `isDisplayed`:

```
var elems = element.all(by.className('bill'));
expect(elems.reduce((acc, e) => acc && e.isDisplayed())).toBeTruthy();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I did this:

```
let billEls = element.all(by.className('bills'));

billEls.then(elements => {
  elements.forEach(el => {
    expect(el.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
  })
});
```

but would have preferred the @FlorentB's .reduce method.