# Time out error using protractor with loops

Tags: selenium, typescript, protractor, cucumber

Brief introduction to the problem. So my project is using BDD Framework (Cucumber) automated with help of Protractor/Selenium using Typescript as scripting language. I passed a table with multiple rows to the step definition and want to run the function in iteration mode using typescript/javascript. I pass the expected dropdowns values and verify it against the application. I came with the below solution with help of one topic on stack overflow. ([Using protractor with loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910331/using-protractor-with-loops))

But the problem is that it does not work all the time. Many times i have got function time out error.(*Error: function timed out after 30000 milliseconds*)

Can anyone please let me know what am i missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please find below Cucumber and Typescript code.

[Cucumber Step Definition_Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lhRM.png)

```
@then(/^.*verify the country data in both the citizenship drop downs$/, 'extratime', 30000)

public VerifyCountryData(table, callback: CallbackStepDefinition): void {
        let promises = []
        let dropcheck
        let dropcheck1
        let promise
        let noOfRows
        var i,j;
        var i1,j1;
        var k,l;
        var funcs = [];
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            let index = i;
            funcs[i] = function(index) {




  promises.push(element(by.model('vm.citizenships['+index+'].citizenshipCd')).all(by.tagName('option')).getText().then((CitizenValueList) => {
                        var dropdown = table.rows()[index][1].split(";")
                        for (i1 = 0; i1 < dropdown.length; i1++) {
                            dropcheck = false;
                            for (j1 = 0; j1 < CitizenValueList.length; j1++) {
                                if (dropdown[i1] === CitizenValueList[j1]) {
                                    dropcheck = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!dropcheck) {
                                callback("Passed value: '" + dropdown[i1] + "' not found")
                            }
                        }


                        for (k = 0; k < CitizenValueList.length; k++) {
                            dropcheck1 = false;
                            for (l = 0; l < dropdown.length; l++) {
                                if (CitizenValueList[k] === dropdown[l]) {
                                    dropcheck1 = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!dropcheck1) {
                                callback("Application value: '" + CitizenValueList[k] + "' not found in expected")
                            }
                        }

                }))

            }.bind(null, i);
        }
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            funcs[j]();
        }

       Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
            callback();
        }, (error) => {
            callback(error);
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see in your code you loops will take more then 30 seconds, that's the timeout you gave in the `@then(/^.*verify the country data in both the citizenship drop downs$/, 'extratime', 30000)`. If you change it to for example `60000` you have more time for this method.

Upgrading the time is a temporary solution in my opinion, you also need to find the `root`-cause of exceeding the 30 seconds time limit. One of the problems can be a slow connection which results in not retrieving the webdriver-calls fast enough. Are you testing it locally or against a cloud solution? The experience I have with cloud solutions is that 1 webdriver-call can take up to 1 second. If you compare it to local testing than local webdriver-calls just take a few milliseconds.

About the code. Depending on the version of Typescript you have (I think you need at least version 2.1) you can use `async/await`. This will remove all the `promises.push(..)`, `Promise.all(promises)` hell and introduce a more clean code like this

```js
@then(/^.*verify the country data in both the citizenship drop downs$/, 'extratime', 30000)
public async VerifyCountryData(table): Promise < void > {
  const citizenValueListOne = await element(by.model('vm.citizenships[1].citizenshipCd')).all(by.tagName('option')).getText();
  const dropdownOne = table.rows()[1][1].split(';');
  const citizenValueListTwo = await element(by.model('vm.citizenships[2].citizenshipCd')).all(by.tagName('option')).getText();
  const dropdownTwo = table.rows()[2][2].split(';');

  for (let i1 = 0; i1 < dropdownOne.length; i1++) {
    let dropdownOnecheck = false;
    for (let j1 = 0; j1 < citizenValueListOne.length; j1++) {
      if (dropdownOne[i1] === citizenValueListOne[j1]) {
        dropdownOnecheck = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!dropdownOnecheck) {
      Promise.reject(`Passed value: '${dropdownOne[i1]}' not found`);
    }
  }

  for (let k = 0; k < citizenValueListTwo.length; k++) {
    let dropdownTwocheck = false;
    for (let l = 0; l < dropdownTwo.length; l++) {
      if (citizenValueListTwo[k] === dropdownTwo[l]) {
        dropdownTwocheck = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!dropdownTwocheck) {
      Promise.reject(`Application value: '${citizenValueListTwo[k]}' not found in expected`);
    }
  }

  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

This can also have an impact on the execution time.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Really appreciate it. Well, my project is using Typescript version 1.8.10 so i will need to upgrade it to version 2.1.0 in order to utilize the async/await Typescript features. Meanwhile, I will try to increase the wait period to 60000 or more. As you correctly stated as I am testing against the cloud solution the webdriver call is taking some time and hence it is giving me the timeout errors.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/wswebcreation/protractor-cucumber-typescript-boilerplate) example project can help you

Comment: Thanks so much. This link is helpful!

Comment: I know, it's mine 

Comment: That's great. Well explained