# For loop prints log to console prior to the action actually occurred

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

i am automating a spec which create `sales quotation`

```
for(var j=0;j<1000;j++)
{    
  element(by.cssContainingText('option','Sales Quotation')).click();
  element(by.id('Vendor_Customer_Name')).sendKeys("Abc enterprise");
  browser.driver.sleep(2000); // wait for rendring data
  element.all(by.css(".ui-corner-all")).first().click();
  for(var i=0; i<data.length;)
  {
    element(by.id('ItemCode_1')).sendKeys(data[i].Value);
    i++;
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
    element(by.id('ItemQty_1')).sendKeys(data[i].Value); //Qty for quote
    i++;           
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).perform();
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).perform();
    element(by.id('ItemRate_1')).sendKeys(data[i].Value);
    i++;
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).perform();
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).perform();
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).perform();
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
  }
  element(by.id('lnkSubmit')).click();
  element(by.xpath('//*[@id="lblSuccessMessage"]/button')).click();
  console.log("Sales Quotation No... ->"+j);
}
```

What it does is it prints sales quotation no. from 1 to 1000 prior to any single Sales Quote is really created how can i make it to print 1 by after Sales quotation is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that protractor uses promises.

refer [Using protractor with loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910331/using-protractor-with-loops)

I think using let instead of var will solve the issue

Comment: this does print directly last value which is 1000

Comment: Is my problem definition was correct. can you show the output and explain a bit

Comment: `console.log(j);` prints out 1000 on every time `.then` executed

Comment: try adding a browser.sleep(1000) btw the click events

Comment: My answer was wrong. thinking It happening due to promises

Comment: its not totally wrong actually loop is not waiting for promise it prints the last value as the looping is done with its process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184456/discussion-between-anandu-s-and-rao).