# For loop in protractor is giving error at the last number in that loop "No element found using locator: By(css selector, span.ng-binding)"

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have been starting with the AngularJS Application testing .
I need to give multiple Answer to an Questionnaire that come after selecting some Symptoms.
Questions are having text or radio button as input fields their are question with 2 radio buttons or 3 radio buttons

```js
//First method Code Giving the same error 
// Questionnaire
obj.questionnaire_row.each(function(question) {
  question.element(by.model("data.answer")).click().sendKeys(d.Easycirmmail.answers);
});


//Second method for answering the questions
function questions(index) {
  obj.questionnaire_row.get(index).element(by.css("span.ng-binding")).getText().then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
  obj.questionnaire_row.get(index).element(by.model("data.answer")).click().sendKeys(d.Easycirmmail.answers);
}
obj.questionnaire_row.count().then(function(qcount) {
  console.log("Question " + qcount);
  for (var i = 0; i <= qcount; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    questions(i);
    if (i == qcount - 1) {
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

[These are the question asked in the ng-repeater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1pBl.png)

---

//this is the Console output:

```
Started
Count 14
Master 2
Master 1
Master 11
Master 0
Master 4
Count 15
Symptoms 7
Symptoms 1
Symptoms 6
Symptoms 1
Symptoms 14
Symptoms 3
Symptoms 7
Symptoms 8
Symptoms 12
Symptoms 3
Symptoms 8
Symptoms 11
Symptoms 3
Symptoms 10
Symptoms 10
Question 45
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
Q) How long has it been since the pain started?
Q) Did he suffer a traumatism?
[10:55:48] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:49] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Did the patient have alcoholic drinks?
[10:55:49] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:49] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Did he stay too long in the sun or in a very hot place?
[10:55:49] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:49] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Did the patient have any sexual intercourse?
[10:55:50] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:50] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Did he suffer from it in the past?
[10:55:50] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:50] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Is there nausea or vomit?
[10:55:50] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:50] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Is he shivering?
[10:55:50] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:51] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Are there spots, blisters or other lesions on the genitals?
[10:55:51] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:51] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Is there any penis secretion?
[10:55:51] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:51] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Is there any swelling of the glands or pain in the groins region?
[10:55:52] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:52] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Are the internal organs suspected of having been damaged?
[10:55:53] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:53] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Describe the traumatism: bruise, contusion, abrasion, excoriation, superficial wound, deep penetrating wound
Q) Is the patient constipated
[10:55:54] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:54] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Does he have diarrhoea?
[10:55:54] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:54] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Is the urine red?
[10:55:54] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:55] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Is there any blood in the urine?
[10:55:55] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:55] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Does the patient have any trouble passing water?
[10:55:55] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:55] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Is any blood coming from the patient’s mouth?
[10:55:56] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:56] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Was there a loss of consciousness or a feeling of fainting?
[10:55:56] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:56] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Does the patient have acclereted heartbeats and cold perspiration?
[10:55:56] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:56] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Does he have a feeling of nausea or vomit?
[10:55:56] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:57] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Has he got breathing difficulties, a lack of air?
[10:55:57] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:57] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
Q) Take a picture
Q) Are the faeces black (like coffee grounds)?
[10:55:57] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
[10:55:58] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.model("data.answer") - the first result will be used
F


//And the error is as follows:
Failures:
1) Easy Cirm Testing  4.Actions Easy Cirm Mail
  Message:
    Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, span.ng-binding)
  Stack:
    NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, span.ng-binding)
        at elementArrayFinder.getWebElements.then (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:814:27)
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
        at C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)Error
        at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:459:27)
        at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as getText] (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:91:29)
        at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as getText] (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:831:22)
        at questions (C:\Users\3 Cube\Easy-Cirm-Automation\ListCrewPage.js:257:93)
        at C:\Users\3 Cube\Easy-Cirm-Automation\ListCrewPage.js:266:29
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
        at C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
    From: Task: Run it("4.Actions Easy Cirm Mail") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:19)
        at C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:64:48
        at ControlFlow.emit (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\events.js:62:21)
        at ControlFlow.shutdown_ (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2674:10)
        at shutdownTask_.MicroTask (C:\Users\3 Cube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2599:53)
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (C:\Users\3 Cube\Easy-Cirm-Automation\ListCrewPage.js:150:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\3 Cube\Easy-Cirm-Automation\ListCrewPage.js:132:1)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], dumping 180 lines of unreadable code / output doesn't help

Comment: Why do you say it is on the last one. From the output, it seems like you only get to 23 questions? Is it possible you have moved on to something else before these promises got resolved? Also, I see the break, but I think i<qcout where you have <= is cleaner. Some of the flakiness may relate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910331/using-protractor-with-loops/55603487#55603487

Comment: @Lino i will be reformatting the question and asking about it

Comment: @JeremyKahan i have tryed with the links you provided but getting error with the awaits example.

Comment: So I wasn't really pointing you to my answer there, but if you want to go that route, you want to declare the function "async" and avoid mixing "then" with async, await.

Comment: @JeremyKahan Thanks for the Guidance.I have just make the Function Async and it is getting execute.

Comment: Excellent. Perhaps you want to post your own answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Questionnaire
async function questionsfunction(index) { //async and awaits keyword is used to complete the function as called in the loop and then after i must be increased.
  await obj.questionnaire_row.get(index).element(by.css("span.ng-binding")).getText().then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
  console.log("Index: " + index);
  await obj.questionnaire_row.get(index).element(by.model("data.answer")).click().sendKeys(d.GenerateEvent.answers);
}

obj.questionnaire_row.count().then(function(qcount) {
  console.log("total Question " + qcount);
  console.log("Question " + (qcount - 1));
  for (let i = 0; i <= qcount - 2; i++) { //Used "-2" for the loop, Reason as the Last object in the ng-repeat is not having any question and answer
    console.log(i);
    questionsfunction(i);
  }
});
```