# How to click on a web element until alert message is visible in screen?

Tags: typescript, protractor

In my application there is a Click to add email link , on clicking on the same link multiple times , alert message comes that you have reached the maximum limit.

How should I implement using protractor with typescript. I used for loop, but it didn't work

```
for (let i:number=1; i<5; i++){   
    if (EmailLinkpageElement.isDisplayed())
    {   
        // click on the link
    }
    else
    {
        // verify the text message
    }
}
```

Please suggest what to do as I am trying but couldn't reach to any solution.

Comment: Please share the error for your implementation. try using `isPresent()` instead of `.isDisplayed()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910331/using-protractor-with-loops This might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you want to click an element for unknown amount times until alert is present. So, maybe you can go with this approach:

This function takes an `ElementFinder` object which is clicked repeatively until either a given `timeout` is reached OR the alert box is present.

```js
const clickElementUntilAlertPresent = async (el: ElementFinder, timeout: number = 10 * 1000): Promise<boolean>=> {
    const clickDelay = 100
    let done = false

    // start interval for clicking element repeatively
    const interval = setInterval(() => {

        // IF the function is done, clear interval,
        if(done) {
            console.log("stop clicking element now", el.locator.toString())
            clearInterval(interval)
            return
        }

        console.log("clicking element", el.locator.toString())
        el.click()
    }, clickDelay)


    // wait until alert box is present. After timeout, returns false. 
    const result = await browser.wait<boolean>(browser.ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent(), timeout)
    
    // Result is now true if alert is present, or false, if timeout reached.
    // Important here, to set done to true. We want to stop clicking interval!
    done = true

    return result
}
```

### Note

You should learn about `Promise` class.
For example,

`if (EmailLinkpageElement.isDisplayed()) { }`

Will always be true, since this returns a `Promise` object, and an object is evaluated as `truethy` in javascript.

If you are not familiar with `Promise` class, then your first priority now should be to learn them! You need them for `async` tasks and in testing it's a lot..

Here's one ressource: [Promise](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-promises-in-javascript-13d99df067c1)